# PHP - Assigning values within if statements

Tags: php

I read the other day that assigning values within if statements isn't such a great idea.
To be honest i actually use this quite a lot e.g.

```
if(isset($_POST) && $post = $_POST) {
  print_r($post)
}
```

Any idea why that isn't optimal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not least because it's a common newbie mistake to forget that assignment and equality operators are different, so it can easily lead to confusion or difficult-to-detect bugs.

Readability of your code is more important than any micro-optimisations

Comment: Readability is of course important. `if(isset($_POST) && $post = $_POST)` is perfectly readable.

Answer (score 10):

Because it is not about being optimal, it is about standards, conventions, the conditions need comparisons not assignments.

***Don't Create The Confusion, Noobs might sit for hours debugging the issue !***

Answer (score 6):

Well, being alone, assignment in the logical operator is not that bad:

```
if ($id = $_GET['id']) {
```

or

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
```

we use pretty often.
Though it's still in danger of readability fault or mixing  `=` and `==` operators.

But mixing logical and assignment operators in one statement is bad. This is called obfuscation and perl write-only style, makes reading this code harder.

So, it's better to be written as

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
  $post = $_POST;
  print_r($post);
}
```

though this particular statement is pretty senseless.
$_POST is always set in any sensible environment and assigning it to another variable not necessary most of time

Answer (score 4):

You could confuse a reader, if you accidentally mistyped `$post == $_POST` to `$post = $_POST`.
In general it doesn't really improve readability in your code...
Besides it is often not necessary to check the assignment with "if"